# Is there a Solana alias system for short readable wallet names?

Tags: address

Is there an alias system in Solana to link short readable names to Solana addresses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is the [Solana name service](https://spl.solana.com/name-service) where readable addresses like `readable.sol` can be mapped to a public key.

You can currently buy `.sol` domain names at [bonfida](https://naming.bonfida.org/).

You can use the [name service](https://spl.solana.com/name-service) program to create your own "top level domain" like `.sol` or `.patoshi`

Comment: Is this what developers use to name their programs?

Answer (score 2):

### Update April 2023

- 'Solana Name Service' ([`.sol`](https://bonfida.github.io/solana-name-service-guide)) is one name service, but **SNS doesn't cover all of Solana**.
- There is also ANS ([`.abc.`](https://abc.onsol.io/) `.bonk`, [`.poor`](https://thepoor.club/), etc)
- Plus wallets like Backpack, Ottr, and Glow have their own usernames.

**The [solana-wallet-names](https://github.com/portalpayments/solana-wallet-names) npm package supports .abc .backpack .bonk .glow .ottr .poor and .sol**

```
import { walletAddressToNameAndProfilePicture } from "@portal-payments/solana-wallet-names";
```

To use it:

```
const walletNameAndProfilePicture = await walletAddressToNameAndProfilePicture(
  // A Solana connection
  connection,
  // A Solana wallet address
  walletAddress
);
```

or to go from address to name:

```
import { walletAddressToNameAndProfilePicture } from "@portal-payments/solana-wallet-names";

const walletNameAndProfilePicture = await walletAddressToNameAndProfilePicture(
  // A Solana connection
  connection,
  // A Solana wallet address
  walletAddress
);
```

**Full disclosure**: I am one of the maintainers of this library.